# Is it fine to say something like "I'm usually being ..."

Tags: verbs

For example "my English isn't much good, so I always think about it when talking with people". Which is most appropriate to quickly express it in English:

- I (usually) have concerns about my language
- I'm usually being concerned about my language
- I concern about my language

Comment: I think it is a question of preference. Though: I'm usually being concerned is - I think - quite contradictory. I would say "I have concerns about my language" or "I'm always concerned about my language"

Comment: "I'm always concerned" - I like it, thanks! P.S. Or even "I'm usually concerned!"

Comment: note: i'm being suggests something in a particular situation, which is contradicted by "usually".

Comment: Ok, so it's either "I'm usually concerned!" or "I'm being concerned!"

Comment: "I'm usually being flogged by Raquel Welch" is syntactically correct (though, alas, untrue).  But "I'm usually concerned about my language" is the better (or at least more syntactically correct) way to express your sentiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I (usually) have concerns about my language.*

Correct, but the adverb *often* might be more suitable.

> *I'm usually being concerned about my language.*

This is unacceptable. Compare 'I'm usually being asleep' / 'I'm usually being cold'. Use 'I'm usually/often concerned about my language'.

> Stative verbs, being used to describe states, often are not written in
>   the progressive aspect, which is used to describe incomplete actions
>   in progress:
>
> eg
>
> We are buying the Tudor Revival house in Somerset.
>
> *We are owning the Tudor Revival house in Somerset.

[Tense, Aspect and Time Concepts In English ... S.Suwono]

> *I concern about my language.*

Incorrect. Unlike the participial adjective *concerned*, the verb *concern* doesn't take the preposition *about* without an intervening direct object, is strictly transitive in today's English, and means 'relate to', 'be a matter that ought to involve' or 'apply to' (or, in another sense, 'disturb/worry').

**Note** This answer assumes UK / US usages.

Comment: Note that in the last example, _worry_ (which does collocate with _about_) would be a much better fit: “I usually/often worry about my language (skills)”.

Comment: Yes, but that's the intransitive 'worry', not as in 'This really concerns = worries = perturbs = disturbs = bothers me.'

Comment: 2) So, simply saying "I'm getting concerned" fits better in second case, can't agree that "being" unacceptable at all - it seems to be just non-recommendable. 3) "+1" for "concern about".

Comment: [These Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%27m+being+concerned+about%2CI%27m+getting+concerned+about%2CI%27m+concerned+about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20getting%20concerned%20about%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27m%20concerned%20about%3B%2Cc0) show a flatline for "I'm being concerned about". Google hits do occur, but largely seem to be from people with other dubious linguistic proclivities, or in larger structures ("Just wanted to know if I'm being concerned for no reason" ...

Comment: // "When I want to tell you what's wrong with your child or grandchild, I'm being concerned. ") Here, the second sentence, if used as a stand-alone comment, sounds non-idiomatic to a British ear. As unacceptable as "I am owning a big old house."

Comment: hm, actually I've found related question - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112166/is-im-being-angry-ungrammatical

Comment: Yes; tchrist addresses the problem with your second suggestion excellently.

Comment: That grandchild example sounds perfectly normal to me—the implied opposition is “When I do X, I’m not being nosy, I’m being _concerned_”. This uncommon progressive works when it’s being used as a contrast to another (more valid) progressive, even if that progressive is only implied. “I’m owning a big old house” could work in a similar context, though admittedly I can’t think of one where it would make sense.

Comment: It sounds perfectly acceptable to me too. 'Here, the second sentence' refers to OP's second sentence: _I'm usually being concerned about my language_. If used as a stand-alone comment, this sounds non-idiomatic to a British ear. In fact, it's hard to think of padding that will license it. 'I'm being concerned' is likewise not good, but I've provided licensing padding in this case.

Answer (score -1):

First we should be picky about where we place the 'adverbs' (-ly words).  'I usually cry with my face to the wall' and 'I cry usually with my face to the wall' differ!  So 'I usually have concerns about my language' means that you 'worry' about it all the time!  On the other hand, if you say 'I have concerns about my language, usually on the speed or while talking in front of a mike', the impact is different.

Comment: I meant, "I always cry with my face to the wall" :)

Comment: Oh! That could mean that you are a 'sad person' - always crying.  It could be 'I cry always with my face to the wall', which sounds better ;)

Comment: I'm not sad just sometimes (sad usually). I'm being sad everyday (usually sad), but not all the time (always sad) .

Comment: @dk14 - "usually," in the context in which you are using it here, would mean: I am normally (or, more often than not) sad.

Comment: How does this address say OP's variant 2?

Comment: “I cry always with my face to the wall” is highly unnatural and clumsy. If you're writing poetry, sure, go ahead and use it. In normal language usage, nobody would phrase it like that. _Usually_ would come before the verb in both meanings. Additionally, this doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Language is more of how it is spoken. Of course, this question is not as much about punctuations, but it could help.  'I cry, always with my face to the wall' may be read better/differently.  It also matters of how we are 'used to' and how we read/perceive English.  In India, we use English like we use our local languages.  This is the reason why we often mix up on the placement of words.  'Generally I visit this community', 'I generally visit this community', 'I visit generally this community' are often taken as mutually replaceable but that is because of the native language that we speak!

Comment: @RaghuramanR No, it's because they really are mutually replaceable, except for the fact that the last option is a peculiarity of Indian English that is very rarely used in other forms of English at all.